# How to use math.random with a minimum and maximum?

Tags: java

For one of my summer labs for comp sci, I have to make a program that takes input for a maximum and minimum variable, then have the computer pick a number in that range using math.random and then give the user 3 tries to guess it.

pretty easy but I can't find anything online that really explains how to do that with a simple math.random.

how can I do this?

Comment: You didn't do very much research, I think.  Even spending 5 minutes searching Stack Overflow alone would have turned up a ton of resources, and probably your answer.

Comment: I find it helpful when searching google about how to do something in a specific programming language to either prepend or append to my search the name of the language. In your case it would have been "java how to use math.random" or "java math.random example"